# In how many ways can you divide the set of eight numbers $\{2,3,...,9\}$ into 4 pairs such that no pair of numbers has g.c.d equal to $2$?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

In how many ways can you divide the set of eight numbers $\{2,3,...,9\}$ into $4$ pairs such that no pair of numbers has g.c.d equal to $2$ ?

My solution goes like this:

> First, we observe, that a pair can have gcd $d=2$ if both the numbers are even. It is easy to see that, any two even numbers paired up, has $d=2$ (We consider the gcd to be $d$), except the pair, $(4,8)$ which has $d=4.$ Now, the odd numbers in the given set are $\{3,5,7,9\}$ and the even numbers in the given set are $\{2,4,6,8\}.$ Now, if we choose any two odd numbers to form a pair, it is possible as all the conditions are satisfied. Now, the thing is, if we want to have all the pairs constituted of only odd numbers, now,this is absurd as, we have only $4$ odd numbers and the maximum possible pairs that can be made with them is $2.$ Now, if we have these maximum number of odd pairs,i.e $2$ odd pairs then, we have to build another two pairs with only the even numbers. This is where, the problem is, since, we can have $(4,8)$ as the only remaining choice and for the $4th$ pair, with the remaining even numbers, left, if we try to pair up, them, in any way we end up, with $d=2$ for the 4th pair. Thus, having $2$ odd pairs, is not feasible. Thus, we can have, atmost one odd pair. So now we have two cases: Case 1: There are no odd pairs in the 4 pairs and Case 2: One odd pair is there. In the former case, we can build the pairs,  either with an odd and even number i.e $(odd,even)$ and  we might take the pair $(4,8)$ as one of the 4 pairs. Here, we have, two subcases. Subcase 1: We have all the 4 pairs of the form $(odd,even).$ The number of ways, this can be done is: We first, choose an odd number and an even number and then continue the process with the remaining numbers i.e $\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{1}}{4!}$ ways. Next, subcase is the case, when some pairs are of the form $(odd,even)$ and we have $(4,8)$ as one pair. Thus, we need to choose 3 pairs, of the form $(odd,even)$. This case is not possible as we won't have  any even number left, to create the 4th pair. Now, this completes case 1.
>
> For case 2, we have two subcases as well. Subcase 1: Out of the to be chosen 3 pairs, all are of the form $(odd,even)$ and Subcase 2: We have $(4,8)$ as one pair decided and the rest are of the form $(odd,even).$ Now, Subcase 1, is not possible, since, we dont have any odd number left to form 4th pair. As for subcase 2, we have to choose 2 pairs. This can be done in $\frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{1}}{2!}$ ways. Thus, the total number of ways is :$\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{1}}{4!}$$+\frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{1}}{2!}.$

Is the above solution correct? If not, where is it going wrong? I know there might be thousands of posts concerning the same topic, but I just want to verify, whether this process is valid or not.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you show an example of how you can pick three (odd, even) pairs along with the (4,8) pair?

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for pointing out the error. I have edited the solution.

Comment: A hint on proof technique: a "wall of text" like this makes it hard to identify the steps of the proof. It may cause you to miss a critical detail (as you did) because you have to keep so much of the whole proof in mind to keep track of what you're doing. Each case and subcase, at least, should be a separate paragraph. You might then notice things such as that you have a Subcase 1 of Case 1 but the other subcase is never given a number. Also just say "Case 1" instead of "the former case." (Probably best not to write "former case" at all until you have a lot more experience.)

Comment: Obviously it's even better to have a simple proof with no separate cases, but sometimes you will have to have separate cases and then appropriate visual presentation of the cases will not only help the reader understand the proof, it will help you write it.

Comment: It also helps if you don't write very large formulas in line with the rest of the text. You can write your text up to the formula, display the formula by itself on a separate line like this, $$2+2=4,$$ and then continue your text on the line after. MathJax or LaTeX will do this for you if you just use two `$` instead of one to mark the beginning and end of the formula.

Comment: @DavidK I will try to keep your suggestions in mind. But can you please, suggest me a way, to create a paragraph in a quoted text. As whenever, I try to do it, the paragraph goes out of the quoted text.

Comment: I think an example makes the best explanation, so I took the liberty of editing your question to start a new paragraph where you wrote "For case 2". The technique is to start a new line and insert a `>`, then start another new line with another `>` followed by the text of the new paragraph. You can also continue the same paragraph by starting a new line and inserting `>` followed by text; this doesn't improve the output format at all, but it is sometimes helpful when you're trying to edit a long paragraph in the edit window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The $2$ must be paired with an odd number.  The $6$ must be paired with an odd number different than that paired with the $2$.  The remaining four numbers can be paired in any way... pick which number is paired with the smallest remaining number.

I get a total of $4\cdot 3\cdot 3 = 36$ total ways.  Hardly any casework necessary.

---

With regards to your attempt, for your case where we have the pair $\{4,8\}$ that would be one (even,even) pair (*which must have been the $\{4,8\}$ pair*), one (odd, odd) pair, and two (even,odd) pairs, there should have been $4\cdot 3 = 12$ outcomes here, not just $2$.  We choose what was paired with the $2$, and we choose what was paired with the $6$, and the remaining two odd numbers get paired together.

Alternatively, you pick the two odd numbers paired together in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, and then you choose how to split the remaining numbers in two ways for $\binom{4}{2}\cdot 2 = 12$ ways.  You seem to have skipped this step of choosing which odds were paired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But where is the flaw in my solution ? I can't seem to find it....

Comment: @Franklin added a second section to my answer commenting on your attempt

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do get it now. I am adding the "fake-proofs" tag in the OP as the solution I posted was incorrect.

Comment: My two approaches are very similar to yours (+1). I added the way to count the number of ways to freely pair $2n$ items, but if you feel that my answer adds too little, I will remove it.

Comment: @robjohn It is effectively the same, but you explained a bit more about freely pairing so... its fine to leave up I guess?  Really up to you.  At first glance I thought you were going to try to tackle the problem of answering number of ways to pair $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that no pair had their gcd equal to $2$, which could be feasible but sounds difficult (*simply pairing the numbers $2\pmod{4}$ to odd numbers isn't sufficient as you could pair $6$ with $18$ for instance*)...

Comment: Interesting extension. I will work on that if it does not detract too much from the original question.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach $\pmb{1}$:**

This is close to the approach in the question.

The only even-even pair possible is $\{4,8\}$ since $\gcd(4,8)=4$. In that case, we would need an odd-odd pair and two odd-even pairs. Otherwise, we would have four odd-even pairs.
$$
\underbrace{\overbrace{\quad\binom{4}{2}\quad}^{\substack{\text{number of ways}\\\text{to choose the}\\\text{odd-odd pair}}}\overbrace{\quad\ 2!\ \quad\vphantom{\binom{4}{2}}}^{\substack{\text{number of ways}\\\text{to assign odds}\\\text{to $2$ and $6$}}}}_\text{pair $4$ and $8$}+\underbrace{\overbrace{\quad\ 4!\ \quad\vphantom{\binom{4}{2}}}^{\substack{\text{number of ways}\\\text{to assign odds}\\\text{to $2,4,6,8$}}}}_{\text{odd-even pairs}}=36
$$
The factor of $\binom{4}{2}$ seems to have been missed in the question.

---

**Approach $\pmb{2}$:**

$2$ and $6$ need to be paired with odds: $4$ possible odds for $2$, then $3$ remaining odds for $6$. This leaves $4$ items to be paired freely. There are $(2n-1)!!$ ways to freely pair $2n$ items. That is, there are $3!!$ ways to freely pair the $4$ remaining items.

This gives
$$
\overbrace{\quad\ 4\quad\ }^{\substack{\text{odds to pair}\\\text{with $2$}}}\cdot\overbrace{\quad\ 3\quad\ }^{\substack{\text{odds to pair}\\\text{with $6$}}}\cdot\overbrace{\quad3!!\quad}^{\substack{\text{freely pair}\\\text{$4$ items}}}=36
$$

---

**Freely Pairing $\pmb{2n}$ Items**

There are $2n-1$ items to pair with the highest indexed item. There are $2n-3$ items to pair with the highest remaining indexed item. Then, there are $2n-5$ items to pair with the highest remaining indexed item. Continuing, we get
$$
(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)\dots3\cdot1=(2n-1)!!
$$
ways to freely pair $2n$ items.

Comment: Actually, the number of ways to freely pair $2n-1$ items is also $(2n-1)!!$. There are $2n-1$ items that can be left out, and then $(2n-3)!!$ ways to freely pair the $2n-2$ items remaining. This can also be looked at as adding a bye and then freely pairing the $2n$ items in $(2n-1)!!$ ways.

Comment: Freely pairing $2n$ items is discussed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4238056).

Comment: Great answer ! +1 from me...